# schedule fsck over SSH

Tags: ssh, fsck

Can one shedule a `sudo touch /forcefsck`

then reboot `sudo shutdown -r now`

and automatically accept any fixes when connected to the PI over SSH?

It's the **accept any fixes** that i'm not sure if its possible over SSH,

but if it is possible, then how do i do it?

Ok ive done some digging and found:

> fsck -A -a -y
>
> The first -A indicates check all filesystems. The -a says "Fix it
>   without asking" and the -y similarly will answer "Yes" to any question
>   it wants to ask you.

Is this 1) what i was looking for and 2) safe to do over terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that.  I have this in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
echo "-y" > /forcefsck
```

So that it happens every reboot (unless I `rm /forcefsck` first).  I think `-a` and `-y` are probably redundant if `-a` means don't ask questions and `-y` means answer yes to any questions.  `man fsck` refers to `-a` as supported "for backward compatibility only" (i.e., it's deprecated).

The system does check filesystems at boot anyway, *if* they weren't cleanly unmounted or have exceeded a certain number of mounts without a check.   However, it's not a `-y` check, which can create a bungle on a headless machine, and it is not guaranteed to happen.

Comment: so 1) this can do what i was looking for 2) "bungle on a headless machine, and it is not guaranteed to happen" does mean it's not safe/ reliable?